# Theatre practitioners book

Tags: identification-request, theater

I'm looking for a book that I used to own and can not find. I think it was American, I had a hardback copy, it was blue and I think it had a black and white photo of actors/directors on the cover. It was a practitioners handbook on producing and directing plays, I think it was written in the 70's or 80's. Any help with remembering the title would be fantastic.